# Python Improve Binary algorithm

Tags: python, binary

So in uni we learned how to multiplicate 2 binary codes. After trying in Python and getting the right result, i wanted to know if i can improve my code with less if statements or if i made any major mistakes without recognising.

```
l1 = [1,1,0,1,1]
l2 = [1,0,0,0,0]
brack = 0

result = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] + l2[i] == 2:
        result.append(0)
        brack +=1
    elif (l1[i] + l2[i] == 1) and (brack == 0):
        result.append(1)
    elif (l1[i] + l2[i] == 1) and (brack == 1):
        result.append(0)
        brack -= 1
    elif(l1[i] + l2[i] == 0) and (brack == 1):
        result.append(0)
        brack -= 1
    elif(l1[i] + l2[i] == 0) and (brack == 0):
        result.append(0)
if (result[-1] == 0):   
    result.append(1)      
    
print(result)
```

Comment: Isn't this binary addition?

Comment: Yes binary addition of the two lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make the bitwise addition without any ifs, but rather using modulo and division:

```py
l1 = [1,1,0,1,1]
l2 = [1,0,0,0,0]
brack = 0

result = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    s = l1[i] + l2[i] + brack
    result.append(s % 2)
    brack = s / 2
if (brack > 0):   
    result.append(1)      
    
print(result)
```